# How can I plot a secondary y-axis with barplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, yaxis, twinx

I'm trying to plot the data (see below). With company_name on the x-axis, status_mission_2_y on the y axis and percentage on the other y_axis. I have tried using the twinx() fucntion but I can't get it to work.

```
def twinplot(data):
    x_ = data.columns[0]
    y_ = data.columns[1]
    y_2 = data.columns[2]
    
    data1 = data[[x_, y_]]
    data2 = data[[x_, y_2]]
    plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
    ax = sns.barplot(x=x_, y=y_, data=data1)
    
    ax2 = ax.twinx()
    g2 = sns.barplot(x=x_, y=y_2, data=data2, ax=ax2)
    plt.show()


data = ten_company_missions_failed
twinplot(data)
```

| company_name | percentage | status_mission_2_y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EER | 1 | 1 |
| Ghot | 1 | 1 |
| Trv | 1 | 1 |
| Sandia | 1 | 1 |
| Test | 1 | 1 |
| US Navy | 0.823529412 | 17 |
| Zed | 0.8 | 5 |
| Gov | 0.75 | 4 |
| Knight | 0.666666667 | 3 |
| Had | 0.666666667 | 3 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seaborn plots the two bar plots with the same color and on the same x-positions.

The following example code resizes the bar widths, with the bars belonging `ax` moved to the left. And the bars of `ax2` moved to the right.  To differentiate the right bars, a semi-transparency (`alpha=0.7`) and hatching is used.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from io import StringIO

data_str = '''company_name  percentage  status_mission_2_y
EER 1   1
Ghot    1   1
Trv 1   1
Sandia  1   1
Test    1   1
"US Navy"   0.823529412 17
Zed 0.8 5
Gov 0.75    4
Knight  0.666666667 3
Had 0.666666667 3'''
data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_str), delim_whitespace=True)

x_ = data.columns[0]
y_ = data.columns[1]
y_2 = data.columns[2]

data1 = data[[x_, y_]]
data2 = data[[x_, y_2]]
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
ax = sns.barplot(x=x_, y=y_, data=data1)
width_scale = 0.45
for bar in ax.containers[0]:
    bar.set_width(bar.get_width() * width_scale)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))

ax2 = ax.twinx()
sns.barplot(x=x_, y=y_2, data=data2, alpha=0.7, hatch='xx', ax=ax2)
for bar in ax2.containers[0]:
    x = bar.get_x()
    w = bar.get_width()
    bar.set_x(x + w * (1- width_scale))
    bar.set_width(w * width_scale)

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

A simpler alternative could be to combine a `barplot` on `ax` and a `lineplot` on `ax2`.

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
ax = sns.barplot(x=x_, y=y_, data=data1)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))

ax2 = ax.twinx()
sns.lineplot(x=x_, y=y_2, data=data2, marker='o', color='crimson', lw=3, ax=ax2)

plt.show()
```

[image: barplot plus lineplot]